# Animation css is not working but the very same code also works(?)

Tags: css, animation

It is a bizarre question.
When I opened up my project, I found out that one animation effect that had no issue before no longer works. So, I downloaded the same project saved in my GitHub. It works!
I copied that github code and pasted to the one with an issue and It is still not working. I restarted the computer and It's same. Google and Safari both.

The one with the problem-animation not working

```
.cv img {
  position: relative;
  top: -12rem;
  left: 30rem;
  width: 15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: click 1s infinite;
  /* margin-left: 100rem; */
}

@keyframes click {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

The another code from Github, which works.

```
.cv img {
  position: relative;
  top: -12rem;
  left: 30rem;
  width: 15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: click 1s infinite;
  /* margin-left: 100rem; */
}

@keyframes click {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Those look same to me.

Html

```
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="human"><img alt="human" src="/img/photo.png" /></div>
    <div class="skills intro">
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/js.png" />
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/react.png" />
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/c2.png" />
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/html2.png" />
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/css2.png" />
      <img alt="skills" src="/img/python.png" />
    </div>

    <a
      href="/resume.pdf"
      class="cv"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      ><img alt="c" src="/img/cv2.png"
    /></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you also add the HTML for your CSS?

Comment: @cloned I just did!

Answer (score 0):

Both of your snippets work, so there must be something else that's causing your problems. Inspect the element with your dev tools and check if the CSS is applied to the element.

```css
/*
.cv img {
  position: relative;
  top: -12rem;
  left: 30rem;
  width: 15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: click 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes click {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

*/




.cv img {
  position: relative;
  top: -12rem;
  left: 30rem;
  width: 15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: click 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes click {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="human"><img alt="human" src="/img/photo.png" /></div>
  <div class="skills intro">
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150g" />
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150g" />
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <img alt="skills" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <a href="/resume.pdf" class="cv" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img alt="c" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
</div>
```

You see that one of the versions is commented out, but no matter which one I comment in, it still works the same.